# Displaying list in Android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I got a fragment that should only display a list but every time I try to display the list the previous activity is displayed in the background.

So my question is, how do I display the list on a empty page? What can I put instead of getActivity() in the ArrayAdapter.

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/fundraiser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

And my code looks like this

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FundraiserFragment extends ListFragment{

String[] values = new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
   (getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear what do you mean  `I try to display the list the previous activity is displayed in the background.` by this statement.

Comment: show total framgnet code

Comment: post code, where you are adding fragment (Activity) and activity xml.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/dCZZtHF) shows what I mean. The activity I call the fragment from is in the background instead of only displaying the list.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that layouts are transparent by default, unless you assign them a background color.

Assign a background color to the LinearLayout of your fragment in the XML file and the parent activity should disappear.

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

Comment: I did this but no change, the parent activity is still in the background.